# Problems submitting to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

Just migrated my website to a new URL.  It all went smoothly except I can no longer submit queries to MySQL database.  I rebuilt my tables in PHPmyAdmin, and can access them as before to retrieve data.  But submit is busted.

```
<?php
  include('./sqlFunctions/sqlFunctions.php');
//link to mySQL database
  $link = linkDB();

//On Submit execute the following code
  if($_POST['submit']){
  //pass link to submitDB().  If errors encounted script will die and pass the errors back.
    $error = submitDB($link);

    if($error){
  //pass errors from php to session Storage to display on reload
      echo "<script>alert( 'Error Encountered' );</script>";
      die();
    }
  }
?>
```

The alert script at the end triggers every run.  So I am assuming that there is a problem with my SQL query.  Looking into the function submitDB() we see...

```
   <?php
      function submitDB($link){
    //variable to hold relavent error messages.  Set to false
      $error = false;

      //Establish Variables from Post
        $title = $_POST['title'];  //etc

      //Check data fields
        if(!$title){
          $error .= $missingTitle;
        }else{
          $title = filter_var($title, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
          $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $title); //etc
        }
        if($error){
            echo "<script>alert( 'Never Fires');</script>";
          return $error;
          die();
        }

        echo "<script>alert( 'This Alert Fires' );</script>";

        //set up our query
        $sql = "INSERT INTO shelters (title, lat, lng, pName, pEmail, pPhone, pContactPub,
        type, oName, oEmail, oPhone, oContactPub, description, descriptionPub)
        VALUES ('$title', '$lat', '$lng', '$pName', '$pEmail', '$pPhone', '$pContactPub',
        '$type', '$oName', '$oEmail', '$oPhone', '$oContactPub', '$description', '$descriptionPub')";

        if ($link->query($sql) === true) {
           echo "<script>alert( 'This Alert Never Fires' );</script>";
           echo '<script>window.location = "'. '../auxPages/mapOfferShelterSuccess.html' .'";</script>';
        } 
        else {
            echo "<script>alert( 'This Alert Always Fires' );</script>";
            $error = $link->error;
            return $error;
        }
      }
    ?>
```

At the end it looks like $link->query($sql) is failing.  But $sql looks good.
mysqli_error($link) also returns no error after linking to my DB with `linkDB()`.

The error for `$link->query($sql)` is:

> Unknown column 'pContactPub' in 'field list

Here is a look at that function...

```
function linkDB(){
   $link = new mysqli(SERVER_NAME, USER_NAME, PWD, DB_NAME);
// Check connection
   if ($link->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
   }
  return $link;
    }
```

Any Ideas?  I've been banging my head against a wall all day.

Comment: instead of if ($link->query($sql) === true) try with if($link->query($sql) )

Comment: Since you just migrated. Did you check your database config? Did you also update it to match your current server?

Comment: @hungrykoala I keep coming back to that, but I have checked and double checked all my settings.  Whats more is that I can pull data out of the database, so I know it is there and responding.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy tried it...  didn't change anything.

Comment: And what is the error message you get from mysql?

Comment: Since you can read from the database then the config is not the problem. I would suggest checking your SQL error logs or apache (If you're using apache) error logs. How do you read from the DB?

Comment: @t.niese like I said above mysqli_error($link) doesn't return an error.  Is there another log you are talking about?

Comment: You say `mysqli_error($link) also returns no error after linking to my db with linkDB()` but you didn't say that you check the content of `$link->error` at the `echo "<script>alert( 'This Alert Always Fires' );</script>";`

Comment: @t.niese, you make a good point, when I try to console.log or alert $error it shoots me the following error messege to the console.  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: That's a JavaScript error, and most likely a result of your _strange_ way of _debugging_ ;) (Those `<script> ... </script>` parts), anyway you still should be able to see the error message in the generated source code at the place where you do the `console.log`.

Comment: @t.niese yea my methodology is... novice in nature.  I used the alerts to try to catch the console outputs before the page refresh.  I couldn't (and still can't) see anything output to console that seems useful when including the $error variable. 

echo "<script>console.log( '" . $error . "' );</script>";
ie. gives me nothing

Comment: How does the final source created for `"<script>console.log( '" . $error . "' );</script>";` look like. Check the source code in the developer tools of the the browser.

Comment: @t.niese GENIUS!  Why did'nt I think of that.  
sorce = console.log( Unknown column 'pContactPub' in 'field list'' );  So it looks like there is a disconnect in one of my table columns.  Gonna dive down that rabbit hole.

Comment: @t.niese like always, a days work, boils down to a tiny spelling error.  Thank you stranger.